# Conditionally returning based on a single value inside Angular 5 observable.subscribe() for chaining asynchronous calls together

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable, spotify

I am trying to chain two asynchronous calls to a Spotify API together - one that gets the names of playlists, and a second to create a playlist if it does not already exist in the list of playlists retrieved. Currently, my code to determine if a playlist already exists looks as follows:

```
  containsPlaylist(playlistToCreate: string): Observable<any> {
this.spotifyService.getUserPlaylists().flatMap(data => data.items).map((item: Track) => item.name).subscribe(name => {
  console.log(name);
  if (name === playlistToCreate) {
    console.log('returning true');
    return Observable.of(true);
  }
});
console.log('returning false');
return Observable.of(false);
```

}

However, this is obviously flawed because the asynchronous call getUserPlaylists() does not have to return before the "Observable.of(false)" statement is reached. Therefore, even if the call returns eventually, containsPlaylist has already returned false (as far as I can understand). I believe this to be the case, as the console will print the console.log statements in the following order:

'returning false', 'playlist exists: false', 'creating playlist', 'returning true'

Below is where containsPlaylist is called, which simply checks if the function returned true or false.

```
this.containsPlaylist(this.playlistToCreate).subscribe(playlistExists => {
  console.log('playlist exists: ' + playlistExists);
  if (!playlistExists) {
    console.log('creating playlist')
    this.spotifyService.createPlaylist(this.playlistToCreate, this.spotifyUser.id).subscribe(data => data);
  }
});
```

So my question is this:

How can I get the Observable.of(false) statement to return inside my subscribe like the Observable.of(true) statement?

Or if that is the wrong way to think about it, how can I modify containsPlaylist to correctly return whether or not playlistToCreate is contained in the existing playlists returned by getUserPlaylists. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it much harder than necessary. In general, when you have an observable, but want another one, you shouldn't subscribe. Instead, you should use an operator:

```
containsPlaylist(playlistToCreate: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.spotifyService.getUserPlaylists().
    .map(arrayOfTracks => arrayOfTracks.some(track => track.name === playlistToCreate));
}
```

Then, instead of subscribing inside of a subscribe callback, you can just use a switchMap if the first observable emits false:

```
this.containsPlaylist(this.playlistToCreate)
  .filter(result => !result)
  .switchMap(() => this.spotifyService.createPlaylist(this.playlistToCreate, this.spotifyUser.id))
  .subscribe(() => {});
```

Comment: That worked fantastically, thank you! One minor change I had to make was adding another .map before the arrayOfTracks map mapping data to data.items.